# Get only last row values from listview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to get only last row of listview. Is it possible? My listview binds with database. Every time it can returns different rows. I just want to get last row. Since I don't know how to do it. I have not tried anything

Comment: use can just use listview length-1 and get the last item using index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var lastItem =  ListView1.Items.LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try *Linq* (the only trick is `OfType` or `Cast`):

```
var result = myListView.Items
  .OfType<Object>() //TODO: out your type here
  .LastOrDefault(); // last row or null (if myListView is empty)
```

Or direct

```
var result = myListView.Items.Count > 0          // do we have any rows? 
  ? myListView.Items[myListView.Items.Count - 1] // if yes, get the last one 
  : null;                                        // null on empty list view
```